# pChart example does not render x and y axis labels

Tags: php, pchart

I am running the Line Graph example in the pChart website.

http://pchart.sourceforge.net/documentation.php?topic=exemple1

The rendered png file is missing the X and Y axis labels as well as the "January" "March" "April" labels.

I ran phpInfo and verified that GD was supported. I am running with php5.

Any thoughts on why the graph gets rendered by not the labels?

Edit: I was able to show the Legend. I didn't not have the required Font directory. But the X and Y axis markers are still missing. by "Markers" i mean that the X axis does not show 1,2,3 ... 20 .. and the Y axis does not show 100us, 200us, ...600us.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to produce the chart. Maybe an issue with the X,Y location values you are using?

Comment: I'm using the code listed in the link I gave.  I copy and pasted it to my PHP editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed: I needed to install the proper fonts.